# Warped product manifold with real and complex parts

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hermitian-manifolds

Is possible to define a warped product manifold $M=(N,g_N) \times f(F, g_F)$ where $(N, g_N)$ is a Riemannian manifold with Riemannian metric (i.e., real manifold with real structure) and $(F, g_F)$ is a complex manifold with Hermitian metric?

Is possible to consider this warped product manifold as Hermitian manifold?

Its metric should be Hermitian because $g=g_N + f^2(g_F)=Re_N + f^2(Re_F) + f^2(Im_F)$, where with $Re_N$ and $Re_F$ I mean the real part of the $N$ and $F$ metrics, respectively, and with $Im_F$ the imaginary part of $F$-metric, being complex.

Comment: I do not even see the (almost) complex structure on $M$. In particular, what happens if $M$ is odd-dimensional?

Comment: @Sebastian Goette - Thanks for your answer, my question born because, for example, a Kenmotsu manifold is a warped product manifold where the base-manifold is an interval $I$ (real) and the fiber-manifold $N$ is a Kahler manifold. Then I wanted to know if, in general, it is possible to consider (and eventually the bibliographic references) a warped product manifold in which the fiber-manifold is Kahler and the base-manifold is a real-manifold where dimension of the base is $>1$.